# passing a unfilled value in database using insert and update

Tags: database, vb.net, insert-update

i has one problem in which i can enter some of a data to the database.Ho can i code this things..i used Insert and update query....the value is type double,integer...and also string.....

Comment: Please clarify your question. I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to say...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it depends on the type of database you are using, but for the sake of argument let it be an SQL Express database:

```
    Dim conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=" & servername & ";Database=" & databasename & ";User ID=" & userid & ";Password=" & password & ";Trusted_Connection=False;")

    Dim sqlstatement As String = "INSERT INTO " & table & "  (ATime,AStringWithLimitedLength,AnInteger,AString)"
    sqlstatement &= " VALUES (@dates,@chars,@ints,@string)"
    Dim comm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstatement, conn)
    With comm.Parameters
        .Add("@dates", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Me.Timestamp
        .Add("@chars", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Me.Type
        .Add("@ints", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Me.UserID
        .Add("@string", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Me.SQL
    End With
    conn.Open()
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
```

You can do something similar with the update statement. For other database types use OleDb instead of SqlClient.